# Random Quote Machine - how to avoid quote repetition

Tags: javascript, random

my question is about a Quote generator I am working on. It's working also onload :), But I would like to omit the situation when the next onclick randomly picked quote is the same as the last shown quote. I would like it to be different. Thank You for Your hints.

this is my js code:

```
var quotes = [
  { text: "Memento mori", 
   autor: "Bractwo Męki Pańskiej" },
  {
    text: "Jeśli możesz sobie coś wymarzyć, możesz też to zrobić.",
    autor: "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    text: "Wszystko jest możliwe. Niemożliwe wymaga po prostu więcej czasu.",
    autor: "Dan Brown"
  },
  {
    text: "Czerp z innych, ale nie kopiuj ich. Bądź SOBĄ",
    autor: "Michel Quois"
  },
  {
    text: "Kiedy łamiesz zasady, łam je mocno i na dobre.",
    autor: "Terry Pratchett"
  }
];

window.onload = function() {
  quoteMachine.initialQuote()
};

var quoteMachine = {

initialQuote: function() {

var newInitialQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

var newInitialQuoteText = newInitialQuote.text;
var newInitialQuoteAutor = newInitialQuote.autor;

    document.getElementById("new-quote").innerHTML = newInitialQuoteText;
    document.getElementById("autor").innerHTML = newInitialQuoteAutor;
  }
};
```

This is the working example: https://randome-quote-machine.glitch.me

As i have written bellow either I am doing something wrong or none of these answer is working. Here is the link to codepen.io, maybe somebody can just have a look and help me: https://codepen.io/hubkubas/pen/oPoJba?editors=1010

Comment: shuffle the quotes array every time you generate a random number

Answer (score 1):

You can hold your last random index in a variable and then after second click randomize until new random is different from the previous one.

Set a global variable for example `let previous = -1` Then:

```
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

while(previous == random)
{
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
}
previous = random
var newInitialQuote = quotes[random];
```

Comment: either I am doing sth wrong or the above code does not work. I have included let prevuios out of the function, the while inside the function - it still repeats sometimes the same quote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a flag is_showed in the data:

```
var quotes = [
  {
   showed: false,
   text: "Memento mori", 
   autor: "Bractwo Męki Pańskiej"
  },
  {
    showed: false,
    text: "Jeśli możesz sobie coś wymarzyć, możesz też to zrobić.",
    autor: "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    showed: false,
    text: "Wszystko jest możliwe. Niemożliwe wymaga po prostu więcej czasu.",
    autor: "Dan Brown"
  },
  {
    showed: false,
    text: "Czerp z innych, ale nie kopiuj ich. Bądź SOBĄ",
    autor: "Michel Quois"
  },
  {
    showed: false,
    text: "Kiedy łamiesz zasady, łam je mocno i na dobre.",
    autor: "Terry Pratchett"
  }
];

window.onload = function() {
  quoteMachine.initialQuote()
};

var quoteMachine = {

initialQuote: function(next) {

var rand_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
var newInitialQuote = quotes[rand_number];

if (newInitialQuote.showed) {
  var next = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    if (quotes[next].showed == false) {
      break;
    }
  }

 if (next == -1) {
   document.getElementById("new-quote").innerHTML = "Sorry I have not new quotes";
   document.getElementById("autor").innerHTML = "John Doe";
   return;
 }
 rand_number = next;
 newInitialQuote = quotes[rand_number];
}

quotes[rand_number].showed = true;

var newInitialQuoteText = newInitialQuote.text;
var newInitialQuoteAutor = newInitialQuote.autor;

    document.getElementById("new-quote").innerHTML = newInitialQuoteText;
    document.getElementById("autor").innerHTML = newInitialQuoteAutor;
  }
};
```